# Evaluating sum of slopes of a signal

Tags: r, signal-processing

I am from India, a novice in Research.

Can you just tell me whether I can take a graph of an ECG signal as input and find the slope of this continuous signal at every given point in the graph. I need to get the sum of the slopes from the input ECG signal.

Is there tool/method to do this activity of finding slope? I am working in R.

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified your question with additional information and more detail about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to sum the slopes at each of a large number of points, aren't you effectively integrating the derivative?

Up to a possible constant-shift depending on where you start summing, and a possible scaling for how frequently you evaluate the derivative, won't you just get the original signal back?

---

Here's an informal argument that should give you the sense of why summing the slopes is essentially (up to scaling and shift*) giving you your series back again:

* and perhaps with some small degree of approximation, depending on exactly how you go about it

Consider that the slope at $x$ is approximately $\frac{f(x+\delta )-f(x)}{\delta }$, for small $\delta $.

Now consider that the sum of such slopes at $x_1$, $x_1+\delta$, $x_1+2\delta, ...,x_2$ is

$$\frac{1}{\delta }\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f(x_1+k\delta )-f(x_1+\{k-1\}\delta)]$$

where $n=(x_2-x_1)/\delta$. Since the first of the terms in each element of the sum cancels out the second term of the next sum-element, this simply leaves the first and last terms:

$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{\delta }$$

i.e. the value of the function at $x_2$, aside from the scaling for frequency (which depends on $\delta$) and shifting for start point ($x_1$) I mentioned earlier.

If you specify exactly how you're computing your slope, and the frequency (if you're not adjusting for the frequency at which you evaluate the slope), and where you start summing from, you can work out the value of the sum directly. Not only will it be faster, it'll generally be more accurate for the thing you probably wanted to begin with.

Comment: Mr. Glen, The graph we need is not smooth. We thus need to find the gradient at a given point and later need to sum up. We are searching for a tool for